# Is htmlspecialchars enough to prevent an SQL injection on a variable enclosed in single quotes?

Tags: php, sql, security, sql-injection

Although many sources quote the `htmlspecialchars` function with `ENT_QUOTES` to be **not** enough to prevent SQL injection, none of them provide a proof of the concept. I cannot think of any possibility myself.

Let us consider the following example:

```
$username = htmlspecialchars($_GET['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$sql = "SELECT * from user WHERE name='$username'";
mysql_query($sql,...);
```

Can any one provide an example, OTHER than ones covered by the case when [SQL injection gets around mysql_real_escape_string()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)?

Comment: what mysql_real_escape_string do?

Comment: PHP's `htmlspecialchars` function is for escaping characters that have special meaning *to a browser*, such as angle brackets, to make them appear as normal characters instead of being interpreted as HTML markup.  It has **nothing** to do with SQL or preventing SQL injection.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The character that `htmlspecialchars` fails to encode the critical character `\0` (NUL byte), `\b` (backspace), as well as the `\` character.

In order to exploit this, you need a statement with multiple injection points. With this you can escape the closing delimiter of one string literal and thus expand it up to the next starting delimiter of the next string literal. Three string literals each with an injection point can then be transformed into two string literals.

For example:

```
SELECT * from user WHERE (name='$login' OR email='$login') AND password='$password'
```

Now with the following values:

```
login:    ) OR 1=1 /*\
password: */--
```

The resulting statement looks like this:

```
SELECT * from user WHERE (name=') OR 1=1 /*\' OR email=') OR 1=1 /*\') AND password='*/--'
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
SELECT * from user WHERE (name=') OR 1=1 /*\' OR email=') OR 1=1
```

Answer (score 3):

Strings aren't the only thing SQL interacts with.

```
$result = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = " . htmlspecialchars($_GET['id']);
```

This is where parameterized queries come in very handy.

Comment: Neither mysql_real_escape_string helps here. So this is not an argument why htmlspecialchars is unsafe in this comparison.

Comment: @mithy Yes, which is why you should be using parameterized queries in MySQLi or PDO. `mysql_real_escape_string` is deprecated along with the rest of `mysql_` functions. I provided an example per your question -  a situation where `htmlspecialchars` on user input does not render the SQL query safe. The question did not mention `mysql_real_escape_string` at all.

Comment: I think he is expecting what input of $_GET['id'] can lead to SQL Injection, if `htmlspecialchars` is used with `ENT_QUOTES`

Comment: @Manu In this example, `$_GET['id']` being `1 OR 1=1` would work as injection, and `htmlspecialchars` wouldn't affect it at all.

Answer (score 0):

htmlspecialchars($_POST["name"], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
can help you alot, but it is not the way to fight against sqli,
becuase this is dosent detect this charecters: ()()()()()()()()()