# PHP: htmlspecialchars & real escape string & quote

Tags: security, pdo, mysql-real-escape-string, quote, htmlspecialchars

I'm programming in PHP5 now, using PDO, not using prepared statements but just "normal" query's like:

```
$oQuery = $oDatabase->query(
  "SELECT
    Content
  FROM
    CMS
  WHERE
    Title = '". $this->TITLE ."'
  LIMIT 1"
);

$aItem = $oQuery->fetch();

echo stripslashes($aItem['Content']);
```

Now I have 2 questions:

1. If I want to insert something, is this enough protection for SQL Injection?

   ```
   $something = quote($something);
   ```
2. Is this enough for HTML *and* SQL injection?

   ```
   $something = htmlspecialchars($something, ENT_QUOTES);
   ```

Look at ENT_QUOTES because this will replace also this: `'`

---

What about this?

```
$this->TITLE = mysql_real_escape_string($this->TITLE);

$oQuery = $oDatabase->query(
  "SELECT
    Content
  FROM
    CMS
  WHERE
    Title = '". $this->TITLE ."'
  LIMIT 1"
);

$aItem = $oQuery->fetch();

echo stripslashes($aItem['Content']);
```

Or should I still use prepared statements?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, HTML and SQL have different special characters depending on the context. So they need a different and context-sensitive treatment.

Even quoted HTML attribute values (using [double quotes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attribute-value-(double-quoted)-state) or [single quotes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attribute-value-%CB%9C(single-quoted)-state)) and [MySQL string literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-literals.html), which may seem similar at the first glance, have a different set of special characters and different escape sequences. In particular, [if MySQL uses backslashes for escape sequences, `htmlspecialchars` won’t prevent SQL injections in string literals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22117157/53114).

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood few things.

**HTML injection:**

`htmlspecialchars` converts special characters to HTML entities.

That's it, it is helpful only for displaying data to a webpage so that someone does not try to inject html. For example:

```
echo '<p> Welcome: ' . htmlspecialchars($_GET['username']) . '</p>';
```

**SQL injection**

You are using `PDO` which is great, but you failed to prepare the query.

You don't escape things manually that's the whole point of prepared statement.

Very very bad to query without preparing in your case, you should prepare.

```
$oQuery = $oDatabase->prepare(
  "SELECT
    Content
  FROM
    CMS
  WHERE
    Title = :title
  LIMIT 1"
);
$oQuery->execute(array('title'=>$this->TITLE));
$aItem = $oQuery->fetch();
$content = $aItem['Content'];
```

You use `query` only when there are not parameter for example

```
$oDatabase->query("SELECT Content FROM CMS");
```

otherwise always prepare to avoid sql injections