# htmlspecialchars_decode shows tags instead of formatting

Tags: php, html, mysqli, encoding, utf

I have stored some mathematics questions in the mysql database having UTF-8 columns as below:

```
htmlspecialchars($data, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

which stores the question in database as:

```
log&lt;sub&gt;2&lt;/sub&gt;(log&lt;sub&gt;5&lt;/sub&gt;625)का मान ज्ञात करें ?
```

Now, I call this question from database to frontend as below:

```
htmlspecialchars_decode($quest, ENT_QUOTES)
```

which shows the following output:

```
log<sub>2</sub>(log<sub>5</sub>625)का मान ज्ञात करें ?
```

while the output should be

**log<sub>2</sub>(log<sub>5</sub>625)का मान ज्ञात करें ?**

How to resolve this? What I am missing?

Comment: Don't do `htmlspecialchars` and `htmlspecialchars_decode`

Comment: Hi, to keep the database secure from SQL Injection attacks as an additional security measure i am doing this. will htmlentities help in this regard?

Comment: Doing `htmlspecialchars` doesn't protect from sql injection.

Comment: it converts single quoted ad double quotes into equivalent html entitites and prevent the quotes to be directly submitted in the database

Comment: From SQL injections attacks, you should use `prepared statements`

Comment: Raad this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22116934/is-htmlspecialchars-enough-to-prevent-an-sql-injection-on-a-variable-enclosed-in

Comment: I am already using the prepared statements. Please let me know using the code specified in the description, what else is required to make the tags work?

Comment: Read my first comment, lol.

Comment: How are you displaying the result? Did you remember to assign the result of `htmlspecialchars_decode()` to a variable, and echo that instead of `$quest`?

Comment: echo htmlspecialchars_decode($quest, ENT_QUOTES);

Comment: I removed htmlspecialchars_decode and just echoed $quest, didnt work. Then i used htmlentities in place of htmlspecialchars_decode, still same output.

Comment: You may be double-encoding it somewhere down the road, not enough code to see where your problem is. `htmlentities` will not help you, nor `html_entity_decode`, even. But what @u_mulder said, you don't need to do any of this to begin with, as far as database security is concerned. If you don't encode it, you don't need to decode it. Simply removing the _decode will obviously not help you here.

Comment: But if i dnt ecode decode the html tag symbols and. Quotes, the application will become vulnerable to sql injection and xss attacks, isnt that so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this: `html_entity_decode(htmlspecialchars_decode($quest,ENT_QUOTES))`
and problem will be solved for sure.

Answer (score 0):

This seems correct when you display this HTML on browser this will render as below:

```html
log<sub>2</sub>(log<sub>5</sub>625)का मान ज्ञात करें ?
```

Comment: No, as i said, this is the output that I am getting on my HTML page as a result of htmlspecialchars_decode()

Comment: Are you storing `htmlspecialchars_decode($quest, ENT_QUOTES)` in a variable and then `echo` ? or you are echoing `$quest`? Just for confirmation

Comment: its echo htmlspecialchars_decode($quest, ENT_QUOTES);

Comment: I removed htmlspecialchars_decode and just echoed $quest, didnt work. Then i used htmlentities in place of htmlspecialchars_decode, still same output.