# How to simulate an SQL Injection attack with mysqli?

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-injection

I have this code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];


$query = mysqli_query($conn, "select name from accounts where name = '{$name}'");
if($query) {
   echo "success";
} else {
    echo "error";
}
}
?>



 <form action="" method="post">
                Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br><br>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add">
</form>
```

And I have written this in the form and submitted, only return (error), and the table was not deleted.
[image]

Comment: Wrong quotes to close the string

Comment: then whats the correct?

Comment: Use error reporting to see what your error(s) are. `echo "error";` is useless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For mysqli, multiple statements or multi queries must be executed with mysqli::multi_query()

So change

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "select name from accounts where name = '{$name}'");
```

to

```
$query = mysqli_multi_query($conn, "select name from accounts where name = '{$name}'");
```

then **retry what you want** in `your own machine`.

Of course, usually hacker will just gain privilege by logging as "admin" and then do whatever he/she wants (in that case just performing single query in a select statement thru a SQL attack will do and do not need to execute multi-queries)

[additional point]

For single query SQL attack, submit the following:

`1}' or 1=1 or '{1=1`

which will become:

```
select name from accounts where name='{1}' or 1=1 or '{1=1}'
```

or

`1}' or name='admin' or '{1=1`

which will become:

```
select name from accounts where name='{1}' or name='admin' or '{1=1}'
```

Hence, to avoid SQL attacks, please use parameterized prepared statements.
For details, you may refer to :

[php mysqli prepared statements select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57891243/php-mysqli-prepared-statements-select)

Comment: then why i need to use prepare for example if mysqli already  secure? my question is how can I simulate the SQL injection with my code or similar code

Comment: See `additional point` in my further revised answer.

Comment: @OsamaMohammed That is not secure. SQL is being manipulated. Maybe not as badly as it can be in older systems but still not what developer intended. Also if you were fetching and outputting content user could add in `union` calls and get data from other tables that was not intended.

Comment: can you please explain this line? (1}' or 1=1 or '{1=1)

Comment: `1=1` will already be sufficient to make the condition to be true if the other logical comparison operators are "or", so it is a normal trick to do it. But usually we may use `name='admin'` to gain super user privilege (AGAIN - please only perform hacking testing in your OWN MACHINES . Thanks)

Comment: thank you, so i can use this also right?
1' or '1=1

Comment: yes sure you can

Answer (score -2):

For example, if you will send like such request:

```
1';DROP table accounts where id!='123454321344321
```

For reason request encoding, you can use + sign instead of spaces.
I am writing an example with PHP simulate `$name` argument:

```php
//That's a mean it is request variable
$name = "1';DROP table accounts where id!='123454321344321";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "select name from accounts where name = '{$name}'");
if($query) {
   echo "success";
} else {
    echo "error";
}
```

Comment: This is not correct and unclear what you mean about `+`. Referring to URL encoding?